# how much time passes between the rifts opening and the kaiju getting to Mt. Fuji in Pacific Rim: Uprising?

Tags: pacific-rim, pacific-rim-uprising

It seems that they have time to repair and retrofit five Jaegers (if you include Scrapper), so this implies that quite a bit of time has passed.  On the other hand, it's an action movie and the implication is that things have to happen quickly.  So how much time has actually passed between the emergence of the three Kaiju and their arrival at Mt. Fuji?